# css3 media queries bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I wanted To Show two Sections in one row both of equal size's when the browser screen become narrower and the third sections should occupy the next whole row but it is not aligned properly kindly some one help me out and check my code where is the problem in code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
     <html> 
     <head> 
     <meta charset="utf-8"> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
     <title>Responsive Layout</title> 
     <style> 

     /********** Base styles **********/ 
     * { 
       box-sizing: border-box; 
     } 
     h1 { 
      margin-bottom: 15px; 
     } 

     p { 
       border: 1px solid black; 
       background-color: #A52A2A; 
       width: 90%; 
       height: 150px; 
       margin-right: auto; 
       margin-left: auto; 
       font-family: Helvetica; 
       color: white; 
     } 

     /* Simple Responsive Framework. */ 
     .row { 
       width: 100%; 
     }


     /********** Large devices only **********/ 
     @media (min-width: 1200px) { 
       .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12{ 

         float: left; 
         border: 1px solid green; 
       } 
        .col-lg-1 { 
         width: 8.33%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-2 { 
         width: 16.66%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-3 { 
         width: 25%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-4 { 
         width: 33.33%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-5 { 
         width: 41.66%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-6 { 
         width: 50%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-7 { 
         width: 58.33%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-8 { 
         width: 66.66%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-9 { 
         width: 74.99%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-10 { 
         width: 83.33%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-11 { 
         width: 91.66%; 
       } 
       .col-lg-12 { 
         width: 100%; 
       } 
     } 

     /********** Medium devices only **********/ 
     @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { 
       .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 { 
         float: left; 
         border: 1px solid green;
       } 
       .col-md-1 { 
         width: 8.33%; 
       } 
       .col-md-2 { 
         width: 16.66%; 
       } 
       .col-md-3 { 
         width: 25%; 
       } 
       .col-md-4 { 
         width: 33.33%; 
       } 
       .col-md-5 { 
         width: 41.66%; 
       } 
       .col-md-6 { 
         width: 50%; 
       } 
       .col-md-7 { 
         width: 58.33%; 
       } 
       .col-md-8 { 
         width: 66.66%; 
       } 
       .col-md-9 { 
         width: 74.99%; 
       } 
       .col-md-10 { 
         width: 83.33%; 
       } 
       .col-md-11 { 
         width: 91.66%; 
       } 
       .col-md-12{ 
         width:100%;   
        } 
     } 

     </style> 
     </head> 
     <body> 
     <h1>Responsive Layout</h1> 

     <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"><p>Item 1</p></div> 
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"><p>Item 2</p></div>   
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12"><p>Item 3</p></div> 
     </div> 
     </body> 
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please **remove width** property from class : ".p" **Or assign '100%' width**

```
p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: #A52A2A;
   /*width: 90%;*/
   height: 150px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   color: white;
 }
```

**CSS**

```
/********** Base styles **********/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A52A2A;
    /*width: 90%;*/
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
}

/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.divBlock {
    background-color: gray;
    min-height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

    .divBlock .divBlockTitle {
        background-color: brown;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        float: right;
        padding: 3px 10px;
    }
    .divBlock .divText{
        clear:both;
        margin:30px 10px 10px;
    }
    .divBlock .divBlockTitle.darksalmon{
        background-color:darksalmon;
    }
    .divBlock .divBlockTitle.brown{
        background-color:brown;
        color:white;
    }
    .divBlock .divBlockTitle.bisque{
        background-color:bisque;        
    }
    .ourMenu{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9
    {
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
        /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    }

    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }

    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }

    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }

    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }

    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }

    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }

    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }

    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }

    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
        /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    }

    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }

    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }

    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }

    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }

    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }

    .col-md-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }

    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }

    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }

    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="ourMenu">Our Menu</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="divBlock">
            <div class="divBlockTitle darksalmon">Chicken</div>
            <div class="divText">I wanted To Show two Sections in one row both of equal size's when the browser screen become narrower and the third sections should occupy the next whole row but it is not aligned properly kindly some one help me out and check my code where is the problem in code</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="divBlock">
            <div class="divBlockTitle brown">Beef</div>
            <div class="divText">I wanted To Show two Sections in one row both of equal size's when the browser screen become narrower and the third sections should occupy the next whole row but it is not aligned properly kindly some one help me out and check my code where is the problem in code</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="divBlock">
            <div class="divBlockTitle bisque">Sushi</div>
            <div class="divText">I wanted To Show two Sections in one row both of equal size's when the browser screen become narrower and the third sections should occupy the next whole row but it is not aligned properly kindly some one help me out and check my code where is the problem in code</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [i wanted to display my html page exactly like that][1]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5gqE8.jpg` 
         <div class="row"> 
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p></p></div> 
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p>Orange</p</div>   
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p>Pineapple</p</div> 
</div>  
p { 
 border: 1px solid black; 
  background-color: #A52A2A;  
  height: 150px; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  font-family: Helvetica; 
   color: white; 
   }

Comment: I have updated new html and css in my post please look it

Answer (score 0):

just use proper bootstrap classes property.

```
p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: #A52A2A;
   width: 100%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   color: white;
 }

.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 128, 0);
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: have u check the image how can i add the heading within paragraph and align this heading to the right most